# What is information gain ratio?

Tags: data-mining, information-theory

With respect to data mining, what is information gain ratio?

I'm a complete beginner to data analytics and mining, so please explain at a low level of understanding.

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio?

Comment: yes @Kodiologist I read that but, I really couldn't understand it.